# Paypal send personal details to checkout page

Tags: php, paypal

Anybody know how to send values like Name, email, city, country, phone etc to populate the new account form on the paypal checkout page? I am taking billing and shipping address on my site only. just want to send the same to the checkout page so that the user won't have to fill it up again on that page.

I am using the paypal ipn class from http://www.micahcarrick.com/04-19-2005/php-paypal-ipn-integration-class.html

Please help!

Comment: Are you sure the billing info is available? I thought PayPal shielded this info from the seller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to implement the [Express Checkout](https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-1122?ct=t(x)) documentation located [here](https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-1122?ct=t(x)).

> In an Express Checkout flow, a buyer still checks out at thebeginning of the flow and pays on your site; however, the buyerdoes not reenter shipping, billing, or payment information, becauseit is already available from PayPal. This simplifies and expeditesthe checkout process. The buyer can then proceed to review the orderon your site. You can include other necessary checkout steps. Youcan also up-sell to the buyer on your Review Order page.

(Others have noted the teribble formatting of the paypal documentation in its current state, namely the lack of spaces.  Hopefully they'll get that sorted out soon.)

You can use `GetExpressCheckout` to get a customer's shipping information so that you can store it. As stated in the documentation `GetExpressCheckout` "obtains information about the buyer fromPayPal, including shipping information."